# MySQL - Split Delimited Right and Left Values

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a case where I will get input for products and their values separated with a delimited special character. Using this string I need to separate products and their values to MySQL Rows like below.

Input:

```
{"1301":29.00,"1302":25.01,"1306":50.09,"1678":100.00}
```

Output:

```
Product ID      Value
1301             29.00
1302             25.01
1306             50.09
1678             100.00
```

Here the products Id counts are dynamic, we can get n count every time. Please help me getting the above output in MySQL.

Comment: This is really more easily done outside the database with a tool like PHP or python.

Comment: The input looks like JSON. MySQL has JSON functions and even a native JSON data type, have you had a look at them? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html

Comment: Maybe you can get it working with those JSON functions and some creative SQL usage but it will not be ideal @Tomalak MySQL is not that mature when "parsing" JSON.. the problem is here that the topicstarter is working with dynamic JSON values as keys like Gordon Linoff  has suggested better is to do this in the application..

Comment: Yes agree with you @GordonLinoff but the actual requirement has to be do with MySQL.

Comment: @RaymondNijland That sounds very much like FUD. JSON parsers are nothing that software needs to be "mature" for. If they are part of the feature set in MySQL then they will work.

Comment: FWIW, to list the keys of a JSON-encoded object, `json_keys` can be used (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-keys).

Comment: @Tomalak i geuss you didn't read *the problem is here that the topicstarter is working with dynamic JSON values as keys* so i will repeat it.. MySQL does not have something like PHP `json_encode()`  which can handle dynamic keys automatic.. In MySQL you will need to be creatively using other SQL with JSON functions to pull this off..

Comment: I read that part. And no, not really. You can use `json_keys()` when you don't know the keys ahead of time.

Comment: yes then you would need to write a SQL number generator and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to parse out  the `json_keys()` output @Tomalak to make it dynamiclly work with `JSON_EXTRACT()` to get the values in one SQL query.. right? This is better handled in the application code and much easier in most programming lauaguges...

Comment: *That sounds very much like FUD. JSON parsers are nothing that software needs to be "mature" for. If they are part of the feature set in MySQL then they will work.* @Tomalak yes like i said before they will work but you would need to use creative SQL also.. To get past mine "FUD" which i don't have.. Check [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mUt8i3Wo12hsyU29YHkQHn/2) is it really that easy using JSON functions to parse dynamic JSON values as keys in MySQL what do you think?

Comment: I would use a loop, @Raymond. It's not as hard as you are making it in your answer. This is a data loading operation. In any external, non-SQL language, as you suggest, one would use a loop as well. There literally is no advantage in bending over backwards to make this a set operation. And yes, nebulously claiming that JSON parsing in MySQL would somehow be "not that mature" without bringing forward anything to back up this claim is FUD.

Comment: *I would use a loop* @Tomalak that would so it still would require you into writting a stored procedure in MySQL which also can be complex. *And yes, nebulously claiming that JSON parsing in MySQL would somehow be "not that mature" without bringing forward anything to back up* i think you understood that wrong i metioned like PHP `json_encode()` which i consider more suited for this that why i called MySQL method to be less "mature" because you require to write alot more extra code to handle it.

Comment: Absolutely, it would mean writing a stored procedure. That would be necessary anyway, because one would need a cursor to go over the import table, assuming that the OP has many rows of these JSON documents to import. It's more complex than a typical SELECT statement, but certainly less complex than your CROSS JOIN+number generator. I have implemented that for this question, and it's less than 30 lines of SQL, probably can be squeezed even more, is straight-forward to understand and (most importantly) it has no arbitrary limits.

Comment: @Tomalak late reaction i was back for a review on mine on answer.. a stored procedure can take a lot more processing resources vs a normal query. Also writing the same on MySQL 8.0 would have much more easy as the JSON functions are more "mature" iám talking about the [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function which is in mine opinion the real  "full blown" JSON parser in MySQL comparable with PHP's `json_encode()` but even better as you can control the output more easy, yes i know off PHP's JSONSerialize interface which also makes that possible.

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat, as the saying goes. A stored procedure is not a lot different from a loop in an imperative language like PHP. I'd expect it to outperform PHP since there is only one engine involved doing the work. In the end trying different options and comparing performance is inevitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL only solution with JSON functions.

**Query**

```
 SELECT 
  TRIM(REPLACE(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(json_parsed, ',', number_generator.number)
       , ','
       , -1
     )
     , '"'
     , ''
   ))  AS 'Product ID'
 , JSON_EXTRACT(json, CONCAT('$.', SUBSTRING_INDEX(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(json_parsed, ',', number_generator.number)
     , ','
     , -1
   ))) AS 'Value'
FROM (

  SELECT 
   @row := @row + 1 AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION   SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION  SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row2
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0 
  ) init_user_params 
) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN (

    SELECT  
        SUBSTRING(json_keys, 2, json_keys_length - 2) AS json_parsed
      , json_keys
      , json
      , JSON_LENGTH(json_keys) AS json_array_length                       
    FROM (
       SELECT 
            JSON_KEYS(record.json) AS json_keys
          , json
          , LENGTH(JSON_KEYS(record.json)) AS json_keys_length
       FROM (
          SELECT 
             '{"1301":29.00,"1302":25.01,"1306":50.09,"1678":100.00}' AS json
          FROM  
            DUAL  
       ) AS record                     
    ) AS json_information  
  ) AS json_init
WHERE
 number_generator.number BETWEEN 0 AND json_array_length
```

**Result**

```
| Product ID | Value |
| ---------- | ----- |
| 1301       | 29.0  |
| 1302       | 25.01 |
| 1306       | 50.09 |
| 1678       | 100.0 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mUt8i3Wo12hsyU29YHkQHn/2)

Comment: Yo!! Working like a charm. Thanks @Raymond.

Comment: @Shanthanu365 keep in mind there is a **hard** limit of 100 values with this SQL number generator.. If you need more you need to add more `CROSS JOINS` .. `row3` max 1000 values `row4` max 10000 values

Answer (score 1):

You really should be treating this like JSON, but you can use brute-force string methods.  Here is one method:

```
select replace(substring_index(str, ':', 1), '"', '') as product_id, substring_index(str, ':', -1) as value
from (select replace(replace(substring_index(@x, ',', 1), '{', ''), '}', '') as str) x
union all
select replace(substring_index(str, ':', 1), '"', '') as product_id, substring_index(str, ':', -1) as value
from (select replace(replace(substring_index(substring_index(@x, ',', 2), ',', -1), '{', ''), '}', '') as str) x
union all
select replace(substring_index(str, ':', 1), '"', '') as product_id, substring_index(str, ':', -1) as value
from (select replace(replace(substring_index(substring_index(@x, ',', 3), ',', -1), '{', ''), '}', '') as str) x
union all
select replace(substring_index(str, ':', 1), '"', '') as product_id, substring_index(str, ':', -1) as value
from (select replace(replace(substring_index(substring_index(@x, ',', 4), ',', -1), '{', ''), '}', '') as str) x;
```

along with a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aaab7e2bafd3518465fb623cb43f89af).